# With Applescript I need to use System Events to navigate a Finder Window that opens within an application

Tags: macos, applescript

I'm currently writing some Applescript to import some material into software which doesn't have much applescript support and virtually no documentation on Applescript.  The two methods are to somehow adapt this script to work:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items 

try 

tell application "Isadora" 

import media into document 1 from these_items 

end tell 

on error msg 

display dialog "Error importing file into Isadora: " & msg 

end try 

end adding folder items to
```

However when I try to use "import media into document 1 from ________" I always get an error, in every incarnation of that combination.

My second approach then is using System Events to navigate through the menu bar to import everything.  When I get to the import part of things where I can navigate and select the files, a finder window pops up.  My question is:
How do I navigate this finder window within the application?  This is like the inception of scripts.  A finder window within a program.
I tried a few simple things like calling the front window of finder to navigate somewhere and what not.  The current script that gets me to the import window is:

```
tell application "IsadoraCore"

    activate
    delay 2
    tell application "System Events"
        click menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "IsadoraCore"
        click menu item "Import Media..." of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "IsadoraCore"
    end tell
end tell
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the "import media" window is a Finder window where you select a file to import. This window is easy to handle. To select the file you must have the posix path of the file. In that window if you keystroke "shift-command-g" then you get a text field where you can keystroke the posix path. For example, let's say I want to open a file in TextEdit. The file is on my desktop with the name test.txt. I can do this...

```
set filePath to (path to desktop as text) & "test.txt"
set posixPath to POSIX path of filePath
set aShortDelay to 0.5

tell application "TextEdit" to activate
delay aShortDelay
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "o" using command down -- bring up the "open dialog window"
end tell

delay aShortDelay
tell application "TextEdit" to activate
delay aShortDelay
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "g" using {shift down, command down} -- bring up the "goto folder sheet" in the open dialog window
    delay aShortDelay
    keystroke posixPath -- enter the posix file path
    delay aShortDelay
    keystroke return -- dismiss the "goto folder sheet"
    delay aShortDelay
    keystroke return -- dismiss the "open dialog window"
end tell
```

Notice I have delays after every command. That is good practice when you're using this type of scripting. You don't want the code to run faster than the computer can perform the tasks so the delay gives the computer time to keep up with the code. Notice that I use a variable for the delay. This way I can play with aShortDelay making it longer or shorter as needed to make the script run properly.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Aren’t you asking Isadora to import a list of folders? Perhaps it can only handle one folder at a time?

I don’t have Isadora to test, but you might try this:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving these_items
    try
        tell application "Isadora"
            repeat with the_item in these_items
                import media into document 1 from the_item 
            end repeat
        end tell
    on error msg 
        display dialog "Error importing file into Isadora: " & msg
    end try
end adding folder items to
```